# Problem connecting to remote registry on Windows Server 2003

Tags: remote, windows-registry

Im having problems reaching remote registry on my Windows Server 2003, or at least that is what my backup/replication software supplier says.

Any Idea on where I can start to troubleshoot?
What rights might be incorrect, and where? Any port in the firewall of the server which need to be opened? Any tool I can use to check it? The remote registry service is running btw..

The server is located in a DMZ, and runs with an external ip..
Maybe the guys who set up the server hardened it just a bit too much :)

Help apprechiated!

Answer (score 2):

You need RPC to be running and the associated ports allowed through the firewall: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596

I would also check the firewall logs to see if anything else is being blocked.

Comment: Yes, opening up the proper ports is most likely the issue. When doing that though, and after you verify it works, I would suggest you make sure you only open the ports for the one machine that needs access, not for everybody (for security reasons).